# array assignment in c++

Tags: java, c++, arrays, pointers

In c++ identifier of an array is a pointer and in java identifier of an array is a reference variable(practically a pointer).

Let's say there are an array `a` and `b`. How come in java this operation is allowed:

```
a = b; //the reference that 'b' holds will be copied to 'a' so both a and b point to the same array
```

but in C++ the same action will be considered an invalid assignment.

If `a` and `b` are both pointers in c++, why address that `b` holds  won't be copied to `a`?

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect. This affects what follows. A C++ array is not a pointer. Still, the language *could* have supported array assignment, so the general question is good.

Comment: They are different langauges, so they behave differently.

Comment: @juanchopanza i did not say that "an array is a pointer" i said identifier of an array is a pointer

Comment: OK, I meant "In c++ identifier of an array is a pointer". This is incorrect. What happens is that in many contexts, they *decay* to pointers. This comes from the C language.

Comment: @Devolus i know that but it should make sense.if the identifiers are   pointers they should act like one

Comment: In C++ an array is *not* a pointer. It *decays* to a pointer if you pass it around (like passing it to a function).

Comment: I dont know the answer, but i think from a general language design perspective, its good that in C++ we cannot reassign references to arrays (makes perfect sense..). imagine you use new/malloc and create an array of 1000 integers, then you dont call free() and reassign the reference to some other array, then you are screwed because there is no GC in C++.

Comment: @gandalf: *"if the identifiers are pointers they should act like one"* Well, they aren't, so they don't. C++ array references are a *bit* like `const` pointers, but they aren't really pointers at all. It's just that you can assign an array reference to an appropriately-typed pointer, and the array reference will get converted into a pointer to the first element in the array. Which is not the same as *being* a pointer, any more than when you assign an `int` to a `long` and it's converted in the process, that doesn't mean it was a `long` to begin with.

Comment: Also note that in C++, "array assignment" would be taken to mean copying all the elements of one array into another one, not making two identifiers refer to the same data.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are not really pointers, they just degrade down to pointers (which point to the first element they contain.) They actually are blobs of data. You can't change the location of an array in C++ because there is no place in memory where a pointer is stored; it is merely an offset into a structure or the stack frame.

Comment: But you could have an assignment operator that copies the contants of one array into another, instead of having to call, say, `std::copy`.

Comment: But that'd be unintuitive in my opinion, since arrays degrade to pointers (they're not orthogonal to other C designs, like structures.) If you want C++-like behavior, I'd say you should try `std::array` - the only downsides being that multidimensional syntax sucks. (Apparently, there is a C++11 solution to that problem.)

Comment: I agree. It is because arrays behave in a peculiar way in C that it would be confusing to "extend" their interface with assignment etc. That is probably one of the reasons behind this.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the array references are `const` pointers but in Java they are neither pointers nor implicitly constant.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah i hope now the answer looks better.

Comment: Well, "...are implicitly `const` pointers..." is incorrect. Arrays are their own thing in C++. As juanchopanza has pointed out, in many cases they *degrade* to pointers to the first element of the array, but that's not the same thing.